# TeamCity setup and libraries

Tags: tfs, msbuild, continuous-integration, teamcity

I have set up a TeamCity partly. Now it downloads the code from TFS and try to build it using MSBuild which was not successful. I know that I am doing something wrong. I have some library added to my code(An ASP.NET website). I know that it is not a good idea to add dll files to Version Control(TFS), but if I don't check them in, when TeamCity downloads the code, it does not have that libraries so MSBuild cannot successfully build it. I was wondering  what would be the best practice to solve that issue?

Answer (score 2):

For dependency management in .net I would recommend that you take a look at the TeamCity built in nuget feeds. You have a possibility to utilize a feed directly from within TeamCity, acting as a server. As you state, commiting dependencies in (any) VCS should really be avoided...

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what type of dlls you're dealing with.

If they are available on NuGet.org, use NuGet and the Package Manager Console to add the references to your solution. Then just put NuGet.exe on your Build Server, and run

```
NuGet.exe restore YourSolution.sln
```

As your first build step.

If they are in-house dlls, then you have a few options. The first being, as TeNGiL mentioned, setting up a private NuGet repository, and publishing the in-house dlls, to that feed, and pulling from it within your build server.

The other option is just to create a 'References' directory in source control, which holds dlls, reference them in your solution from the source controlled directory, and then pull them down as part of your Build Configuration. This really isn't as bad as it sounds, within reason, and is a perfectly acceptable interim solution to incorporate until everyone is on board with using a private NuGet feed, or something of that nature.

Answer (score 0):

Open the code in the checkoutdirectory of TeamCIty in visual studio and try and build.I am pretty sure that visual studio will give you the exact error message of what's going wrong.

Missing packages have to be restores. Use a Nuget Installer build step to restore your packages as given in image below.

[image: Buils Step]